# rails slim indent syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am trying to design my sites EULA page content and I keep receiving this error:

> Are you trying to nest a child tag in a tag containing text? Use | for the text block!

It seems that all my indents are fine and yet this doesnt work:

```
v#page_content
  .container
    = render 'leftbar'
    .content
      = render 'actions'
      .maincol
        h2 Corp End User License Agreement
        h7 Last Revised: September 20, 2012
        ol
          li
            h2
              u Introduction
            | Welcome to the Corp platform at
            a href="http://www.Corp.com"  www.Corp.com
            |  owned and operated by Social Paragraph Ltd. and/or its affiliates ("
            b Company", "Us" or "We"
            | ). Corp. and its affiliates  invite you to use its online crowd funding academic translation platform, whereCorp students who use such platform (
            b "Users" or "You"
            | ) can share the costs of translation of scientific journals, manuscripts, and research books (
            b "Work(s)"
            | ), and professional academic translators (
            b "Professional Translators"
            | ) and, in the future, also advanced students in the field of the Work (
            b "Students Translators"
            | ) (Student Translators and Professional Translators shall be collectively referred to hereunder as
            b  "Translators"
            | ) can offer their services to Users (
            b "Platform"
            | ). Users can make two types of financial transactions on the Platform: Crowdshare and Individual Transactions (as such terms are defined below).
          li
            h2
              u Acceptance of Terms
            u IMPORTANT:
            |  BY CLICKING THE "I ACCEPT" BUTTON AND/OR USING THE PLATFORM YOU AGREE THAT YOU HAVE READ AND UNDERSTOOD THE TERMS SET FORTH IN THIS END USER LICENSE AGREEMENT,  AS MAY BE AMENDED FROM TIME TO TIME (THE "EULA"). IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO ANY OF THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS OF THIS EULA – DO NOT CLICK ON THE "I ACCEPT" BUTTON AND DO NOT USE THE PLATFORM YOUR CONTINUED USE OF THE PLATFORM SHALL BE DEEMED AS ACCEPTANCE TO THE AMENDED OR UPDATED TERMS.  HENCE, WE URGE YOU TO CHECK FREQUENTLY TO SEE IF WE HAVE UPDATED THESE TERMS. THE MOST CURRENT VERSION OF THE TERMS IS AVAILABLE AT
            a href="http://www.Corp.com/eula"  www.univeersiteam.com/eula01
            b
              u Use of the Platform
            ol
              li
                | Upon entering the Platform, Users may search for a certain Work translated to the language of their preference (
                b "Translated Work"
                | ) by using the search bar [
                a href="http://www.uCorp.com"  Corp.com
                | ]. Such search may derive the following results, depending on whether with respect to such Translated Work, a project for sharing the costs of the translation between Users (
                b "Crowdfunded Project"
                | ) has already been initiated:

      .rightcol
        aside.aside
          == image_tag 'man.jpg'
          p High quality translation guarantee while protecting intellectual property and authors rights.
```

Using the following gems:

```
sass (3.1.20)

sass-rails (3.2.5)

sax-machine (0.0.20)

selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)

shoulda (3.1.1)

shoulda-context (1.0.0)

shoulda-matchers (1.2.0)

sinatra (1.3.2)

skinny (0.2.1)

slim (1.2.2)

slim-rails (1.0.3)
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the `v` tag in `v#page_content`?

Comment: I see the invalid indentation here: `li
                | Upon entering`

Comment: have you need the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your template looks good and works for me.
What about the partials, did you check their syntax, too?