# in slim how can i place in image between 2 lines of text?

Tags: slim-lang

I wand to display logo image wrapped between h1 style lines of text. I am using slim. How can I rewrite this code that it shows all in one line?

```
h1 text1
=image_tag 'image'
h1 text 2
```

or

```
h1 text1 =image_tag 'image' rest of text1
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out:

```
h1 
 |text1 
 =image_tag "image" 
 |text2
```

the solution was inspired by this question which has a great example of using Slim:

[rails slim indent syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735222/rails-slim-indent-syntax-error)